# Shopify page template sections with different data for another page

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am new to Shopify and just started to learn. My problem is, I have created a page template with section which allow to section product, now when I create another page with same page template the page content was same that I have created before, if I change content in second page it will reflect to both pages. How I distinguish sections for different pages?

**Section 1**

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Page Heading",
    "settings": [

        {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "page-heading",
            "label": "Page Heading"
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "page-heading-big",
            "label": "Bigger Heading"
        },
        {
            "type": "image_picker",
            "id": "page-heading-image",
            "label": "Heading Image"
        }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

**Section 2**

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Promotional Blocks",
  "max_blocks": 10,

  "blocks": [
  {
    "type": "single-product",
    "name": "Add Single Product",

    "settings": [
      {
        "id": "single-product",
        "type": "product",
        "label": "Choose Product"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong, but at the moment this is not possible in Shopify. According to [Shopify Theme Docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections#static-and-dynamic-sections)

Sections can be statically included in a theme's templates (like the header and footer), or they can be dynamically added to the theme's home page from the theme editor.

> **Static sections**
>
> You can include a section in a template file using the section tag.
>   This tag behaves like the include tag for snippets: {% section
>   'header' %} will include the section located at
>   sections/header.liquid. By explicitly calling a section this way, it
>   is referred to as being static.
>
> ***A section can be included in multiple templates, but there exists only
>   one instance of that section. When a merchant changes the
>   configuration of a static section in one place, that change will apply
>   to all other places where the section is included.*** Note that sections
>   cannot include other sections.

So a possible solution is to create a new section with same settings in your theme files.

Another possible workaround as defined here

[**Shopify one section / schema for multiple pages : Dynamic sections**](https://sumankc.com/2017/07/19/shopify-one-section-schema-for-multiple-pages-dynamic-sections/)

This approach uses, [Shopify Blocks](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections#blocks) inside sections.

> Sections can define blocks in their schemas. Blocks are containers of
>   settings and content which can be added, removed, and reordered within
>   a section.

What it does is create a block inside section and add additional setting named **page_handle**. So anytime a user adds the new block, user is able to select on which page the block should be displayed. Then in section code, it checks if the **page_handle** selected inside block setting matches the **page_handle** that user is currently viewing. If yes then show the content.

```
{% comment %}
    block.settings.page_handle is what user selected in block settings
    page_handle is what page user is viewing on Shopify site
{% endcomment %}
{% assign page_handle = page.handle %}
{% if block.settings.page_handle == page_handle %}
    {{ block.settings.page_title }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes, I know shopify does not support this kind feature. Is there any way to achieve this? I read this article but I didn't get how I implement this.
Article Link: https://sumankc.com/2017/07/19/shopify-one-section-schema-for-multiple-pages-dynamic-sections

Comment: @WPDev article is pretty clear.. I have added some info, if that helps you to understand more about that approach.

Comment: Thanks @BilalAkbar - blocks is a good method for this